# Where to add field that is calculated from other files in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl real estate adds.

I have field `price` and `size` (in m2), so I can calculate `price_per_m2` as `price/size`.

My question is where should I do this (in what class) according to best practice in Scrapy?

Now I have it in my `scrapy.Spider`, but should I have it in some other place (like pipeline) and how (code examples preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a calculation (or post-processing in general) common to all items, using a pipeline is a one possible way to do it. In real estate, I can imagine for example geocoding addresses or storing each item in database. The main reason behind using pipeline, in my opinion, is that you separate this additional logic out of spiders so you have a single place of maintenance when there's a need to change this logic. In examples given above, you might decide to change the geocoding provider or instead of using one database engine, you switch to another. That's the real strength of pipelines. That said, calculating price per m2 from price and size, which is hardly to change, can safely be put right into the spider code. On the other hand, if there is more such simple calculations, you might consider using pipelines just to save time repeating the same code in every spider.

Answer (score 3):

While I can agree with [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094364/4817209) in some points, I would never put this calculation in the spider itself.

I use spiders to extract data from pages. For me, that is the only purpose of a spider. I use ItemLoader for cleaning extracted data and basic manipulation (like converting everything to the same base unit) . And finally I use Pipelines for any high level data manipulation, like combining fields from items.

Imagine you have a dozen of spiders and you calculate price_per_m2 inside them. Your project has grown and you start coding spiders for another country. You have spiders getting prices in GBP, EUR and USD. Now if you want to compare price_per_m2 you have to 1) convert units in each spider before calculations or 2) add meta data to items in order to do a post processing. Both approaches are onerous in my opinion. My approach: spiders extract data, ItemLoader convert every price to the same unit, some Pipeline calculates price_per_m2 for every item (all them in the same units).

Comment: I selected answer from Tomas, just because he was first, sorry for that :-). Can you explain me why would you convert every price to the same unit in ItemLoader (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors) and not in spyder? I am trying to understand the logic behind the Scrapy framework.

Comment: 1) Ideally I would like to make operations like unit conversions in the item itself. But Scrapy design follows a different approach and I do not fight it. ItemLoader is the closest thing to Item where I can do this operation.
2) It is more DRY: when using ItemLoader everything to do with unit conversions would be in a single processor while if I do it in spiders I would be duplicating code/logic.